# Calling Google Apps Script as webapp from AppEngine returns 405

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have issues when I try to call a GAPPS script that is published as a webapp. I am trying to call this service from AppEngine. I am doing a POST method to this script with a JSON Payload. Urlfetch options are set to follow redirects and a timeout of 30 secs. The script is publicly available and open to anonymous users.

**On my local GAE development machine**, the URLFetch response from the script is 200, and all is fine.

**When I move to production**, the script gets executed but returns errors and an HTML page.
I have follow redirects on on URLFetch and I have set the deadline to 30secs.

**status response : 405**

response text :
 `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ><head><meta name="description" content="Web word processing, presentations and spreadsheets"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/drive_favicon1.ico"><title>Google Drive -- Page Not Found</title><link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><style>/* Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */
.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{color:#91959c;font-family:"Open Sans",Arial,sans-serif;font-size:27px;font-weight:300;position:absolute;text-shadow:0 1px 1px white;white-space:nowrap}#drive-logo img{padding:0 0.4em 0 0;position:relative;top:2px;vertical-align:middle}#drive-logo a{color:#91959c;text-decoration:none}#drive-logo span.goog-inline-block{margin-top:2px;vertical-align:top}</style><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}</style><style type="text/css">.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}</style></head><body><div style="margin: auto; max-width: 750px;"><div style="margin: 80px 40px 20px 40px; position:relative; "><div style="position: absolute; top: -80px;"><h1 id="drive-logo"><a href="/"><img src="//www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" width="116" height="41" alt="Google logo" ><span class="goog-inline-block">Drive</span></a></h1></div><div align="center"><p class="errorMessage" style="padding-top: 50px">Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.</p><p> Please check the address and try again. </p><div style="background: #F0F6FF; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 35px; padding: 10px 125px; width: 300px;"><p><strong>Get stuff done with Google Drive</strong></p><p>Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more.</p><p>Learn more at <a href="https://drive.google.com/start/apps">drive.google.com/start/apps</a>.</p></div></div></div></div></body></html>`

- response header:Expires=Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
- response header:X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
- response header:Alternate-Protocol=443:quic,p=0.02
- response header:Set-Cookie=NID=67=KSieONzrWKqWVEt8E4M2rUo_2nooEJ6qrh80LXTppGKYQux2iGFN-BHoqn7r5Yn0F4WaYtTbXDa6y2iAa3FtRBMAn6qf526lmPkZZek7nSQUvCv4wvthsDsL4P11Yx;Domain=.googleusercontent.com;Path=/;Expires=Tue, 02-Jun-2015 23:39:38 GMT;HttpOnly
- response header:X-Google-Cache-Control=remote-fetch
- response header:Server=GSE
- response header:Cache-Control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
- response header:Pragma=no-cache
- response header:X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
- response header:X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
- response header:Date=Mon, 01 Dec 2014 23:39:38 GMT
- response header:P3P=CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
- response header:Allow=HEAD, GET
- response header:x-chromium-appcache-fallback-override=disallow-fallback
- response header:Via=HTTP/1.1 GWA
- response header:Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8

The funny - no so much - thing is that **the script WORKS NEVERTHELESS most of the time** but not always or not for all users.

You can see that thet response header says `Allow=HEAD, GET` but I implemented `doPOst` in my script.

Nevertheless, I have tried solving this problem by rewriting the whole things to work with `GET` and a parameter but I am running into similar issues !

**Long story short** : works perfectly and with status response 200 on GAE local development server, faulty responses and unstable behavior when deployed to GAE>

Comment: Are you using Python or Java AppEngine SDK ?

Comment: @user3355018 Java GAE SDK...

Comment: I used the code snipped described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet#Using_HttpURLConnection) to make a POST call to an AppScript, and works perfectly.

Comment: @user3355018 do you call a Gapps script ? deployed on GAE or local devserver ? do you send a payload with POST or do you GET ?

Comment: I send a json payload with a POST request (works both from local dev server and from GAE) to an AppScript deployed as web app.

Comment: thx @user3355018, i will try your suggestions. I was using UrlFetch, not the java.net alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

GAS is very picky when running as webapp. Sometimes it helps to put the script into a public folder on Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks @dflorey , I'll try that. For now, I also opened a ticket https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4582